# Use <input> from child Svelte component to search store in App component?

Tags: binding, components, store, svelte

I have a Svelte app set up so that there's an App component, a Chart component and a Header component.

The App component pulls in data. The Chart component displays the data.

The Header component has an `<input>`. I want to be able to enter a search string in that input, in the Header component, and have it filter the data that's in the App component.

I'm not there yet. Here is [my work in progress](https://svelte.dev/repl/6302132989c84496b17be825e112231e?version=3.47.0).

Right now, I have an `<input>` in the App component, too. And that one is correctly filtering my data that shows up in the Chart component.

I just want to be able to use the `<input>` in Header.

I've found how I can bind the header input text to App, as shown in my REPL, but how do I use that text as a variable?

All help very welcome.

Again, here's the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6302132989c84496b17be825e112231e?version=3.47.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are binding the value from the header to a store, while your *local* search input binds to `search`, which you then use for filtering

```html
<Header bind:value={$store} />
<input bind:value={search}>
```

But you are actually not doing anything with this store, not even sure why it is a store since you don't need that part here. Nothing stops you from using bind in a component to connect to a regular value

```html
<Header bind:value={search}>
```